# Moodle - I want to change moodle core plugin "upload" and install it as a separate plugin

Tags: php, moodle

Actually, my requirement is to change the moodle core plugin **upload** which is located in *repository/upload*. And also, I don't want to alter the core plugin code and I just want to install it as a separate plugin. Can I do this?

This is the new code

```
/**
     * Process uploaded file
     * @return array|bool
     */
    public function upload($saveas_filename, $maxbytes) {
        global $CFG;

        $types = optional_param_array('accepted_types', '*', PARAM_RAW);
        $savepath = optional_param('savepath', '/', PARAM_PATH);
        $itemid   = optional_param('itemid', 0, PARAM_INT);
        $license  = optional_param('license', $CFG->sitedefaultlicense, PARAM_TEXT);
        $author   = optional_param('author', '', PARAM_TEXT);
        $areamaxbytes = optional_param('areamaxbytes', FILE_AREA_MAX_BYTES_UNLIMITED, PARAM_INT);
        $overwriteexisting = optional_param('overwrite', false, PARAM_BOOL);

        //return $this->process_upload($saveas_filename, $maxbytes, $types, $savepath, $itemid, $license, $author, $overwriteexisting, $areamaxbytes);
        return $this->process_upload($USER->profile['cbnumber'], $maxbytes, $types, $savepath, $itemid, $license, $author, $overwriteexisting, $areamaxbytes);
    }
```